# Android - Load more data using AsyncTask which gets data from API in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to dynamically add items to my `RecyclerView`.

Basically, I am following Instagram style, especially in the search fragment of Instagram. Currently, my app gets the number of item sent by server (default is 10) and add it onto the number of displayed items on the recyclerview.

I have an interface to get the output from the server, here's the `OnLoadMoreListener`

```
System.out.println("OnLoadMore");
list.add(null);
profilTemanAdapter.notifyItemInserted(list.size());
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //remove progress item
        list.remove(list.size() - 1);
        profilTemanAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(list.size());

        TimelineFriendListAPI timelineFriendListAPIInput = new TimelineFriendListAPI();
        timelineFriendListAPIInput.kevin.query.user_id = userId;
        timelineFriendListAPIInput.kevin.query.other_user_id = otherUserId;
        timelineFriendListAPIInput.kevin.query.friend_mode = friendMode;

        nextFriendList = result.kevin.results.friend_list;
        TimelineFriendListAPIFunc timelineFriendListAPIFunc = new TimelineFriendListAPIFunc(BottomProfilTemanFragment.this.getActivity());
        timelineFriendListAPIFunc.delegate = BottomProfilTemanFragment.this;

        if (nextFriendList.size() == 10) {
            counter += 10;
            timelineFriendListAPIInput.kevin.query.friend_count = String.valueOf(counter);
        Log.d("CounterBefore", String.valueOf(counter));
            timelineFriendListAPIFunc.execute(timelineFriendListAPIInput);
            Log.d("CounterAfter", String.valueOf(counter));
            Log.d("FriendLists", nextFriendList.get(0).friend_alias);
            //Refresh Per Item
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                list.add(nextFriendList.get(i));
                profilTemanAdapter.notifyItemInserted(list.size());
                Log.d("FriendLists", nextFriendList.get(i).friend_alias);
            }
            Log.d("FriendLists", nextFriendList.get(10).friend_alias);
            Log.d("OnLoadNotifFriendSize10", "size = " + list.size());
            profilTemanAdapter.setLoaded();
        } else if (nextFriendList.size() < 10 && nextFriendList.size() > 0) {
            int friendCounter = nextFriendList.size();
            counter += friendCounter;
            timelineFriendListAPIInput.kevin.query.friend_count = String.valueOf(counter);
            timelineFriendListAPIFunc.execute(timelineFriendListAPIInput);
            //Refresh Per Item
            for (int i = 0; i < friendCounter; i++) {
                list.add(nextFriendList.get(i));
            }
            profilTemanAdapter.notifyItemInserted(list.size());
            profilTemanAdapter.setLoaded();
        } else {

        }
    }
}, 1000);
System.out.println("loadMore");
```

Here's the Interface function in the same class

```
result = output; //result is a global variable to be accessed inside the OnLoadMore

//profilTemanAdapter = new ProfilTemanAdapter(list, recyclerView, output);
//createlist();
handler = new Handler();
list = output.kevin.results.friend_list;profilTemanAdapter = new `ProfilTemanAdapter(list, recyclerView, output);`
profilTemanAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(profilTemanAdapterHandler);
recyclerView.setAdapter(profilTemanAdapter);
Log.d("FriendLists", list.get(0).friend_alias);
```

As can be expected, `nextFriendList.get(10).friend_alias` which is the 11th value in the `List`, is still the same as `nextFriendList.get(0).friend_alias` as `nextFriendList` has not been updated through the interface.

How to display it correctly as in waiting for the `AsyncTask` to finish, but not using `.get()` so that it doesn't block UI thread just like Instagram (or any "InfiniteScrolling" app) ?

Small update :

Used `ProgressBar` in Async so that it loads the information gained from server before displaying, but it messed the layout. There's an `EditText` above the `RecyclerView` which gets repeated on every `OnLoadMore`. Moreover it doesn't look nice with `ProgressBar` popping up for every information load..

Another update :

I am able to display `OnLoadMore` items but it replaces the items before the new items.

Comment: `As can be expected, nextFriendList.get(10).friend_alias which is the 11th value in the List, is still the same as nextFriendList.get(0).friend_alias`. No. I did not expect that. Why would it be like that? If 10 is not there yet then it is not there. Better display an empty item when the data did not yet come in..

Comment: Because the first 10 items are still in the `list`, it hasn't been changed to the next 10 items from db as the `AsyncTask` is still ongoing.. How to display empty item?

Comment: With empty String's and émpty' images ... what you want. And i do not understand your setup. Of course the first 10 items are still in the list. But why would you replace them? Add the new items i would think. And if you still want to replace them then reset all items to 'empty' first.

Comment: Hmm.. Does `list.add()` followed with `adapter.notifyItemInserted()` directly add items into the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Meanwhile you tried this already and found out that it worked.

Comment: No, it replaced the current 10 list of items with the new 10 list of items from the server..

Comment: Strange list where add becomes replace. Your idea is ok though.

Comment: Right?? It's very strange.. I've been pulling my hairs out for the past 3 days for this one.. It's very weird!

Comment: I realized it's because of reinitializing of my adapter in the interface function! Now onto passing the output onto adapter to display it inside recyclerview~